# Error while executing dynamically created JUnit Tests

Tags: java, junit, reflection, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke a dynamically created Junit test class using the code below

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    URL classUrl = javaClass.getParent().toFile().toURI().toURL();
    URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { classUrl });
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(fileName, true, classLoader);
    Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
    context.getLogger().log("Test Class Loader==>"+obj.getClass().getClassLoader()+"\n");
    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    context.getLogger().log("JUnitCore Class Loader==>"+junit.getClass().getClassLoader()+"\n");
    junit.addListener(new TextListener(new PrintStream(outputStream)));
    Result result = junit.run(clazz);       
    return outputStream.toString();
```

Dynamically created test file

```
public class SampleJavaFileTest {
  String EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING="r3plac3";

  @Test
  public void testReplaceString() {
    SampleJavaFile sample = new SampleJavaFile();

    String outputString = sample.replaceString("replace","e","3");
    Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING, outputString);
 }
}
```

But I get the error as

```
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(JUnitTest)
org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'JUnitTest':
1. No runnable methods
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:511)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.JUnit4.<init>(JUnit4.java:23)
at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder
  .runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:50)
at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:125)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:111)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:81)
at org.junit.runner.Computer$2.<init>(Computer.java:33)
```

I tried printing the class loaders of the dynamically created class and the JUnitCore class the results are

```
   Test Class Loader==>java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@86be70a
   JUnitCore Class Loader==>java.net.URLClassLoader@49c2faae
```

Upon going through various posts the answers provided are to use custom class loaders to resolve this issue. Can you assist on how to create a custom class loader to resolve this issue?

If not custom class loaders , how else can this be resolved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this exception is generated in this junit block of code

```
 List<Method> methods = testClass.getAnnotatedMethods(Test.class);
 if (methods.size() == 0) {
     errors.add(new Exception("No runnable methods"));
 }
```

So, I'd recommend to double check, that you definitely have annotation @Test for method, and it is really org.junit.Test and this annotation available in runtime.

You can check this by taking klass.getDeclaredMethod("testReplaceString") and printing all annotations from it.

If it doesn't help, then, you can debug Junit library, put breakpoint to exception (please note, this exceptions generated not in the same place, where throwed) and check conditions

BTW, what version of junit do you use?

EDITED:
I've checked your code, I've created a new project in IDEA, added junit 4.13-rc-1 to dependencies and created two files.

```
public class SampleJavaFileTest {
    String EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING="r3plac3";
    @Test
    public void testReplaceString() {
        Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING, "r3plac3");
    }
}
```

and another class

```
public class ClassLoadDynamically {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final File fileForClass = new File(SampleJavaFileTest.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { fileForClass.toURI().toURL() });
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("SampleJavaFileTest", true, classLoader);

        Method testReplaceString = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("testReplaceString");

        System.out.println("Get declared methods==>"+ testReplaceString);
        System.out.println("Get annotation => "+ testReplaceString.getAnnotation(org.junit.Test.class));

        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(clazz);

        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());

    }
}
```

I've checked your code, it works in this way. Please check, how do you generate your code dynamically, looks like the the issue in wrong bytecode generation, double check, how do you set annotations to the method.

However, I'm not sure, about your environment configuration on lambda. Anyway, I'd recommend to make your code run locally

Comment: Hi @Alexander , Thanks for your response! Interestingly `System.out.println("Get declared methods==>"+obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("testReplaceString")); System.out.println("Get annotation==>"+obj.getClass().getAnnotation(org.junit.Test.class));`                     
 returns  `Get declared methods==>public void JUnitTest.testReplaceString()
Get annotation==>null` .  Not sure why the annotation is lost during dynamic creation. How can the annotation be retained?   I am using junit-4.13-rc-1.jar . The code is in aws lambda , hence not sure how to debug the same.

Comment: Well, at first, you should not check obj.getClass().getAnnotation(org.junit.Test.class), instead obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("testReplaceString").getAnnotation(org.junit.Test.class) - you annotate method,not a class, is it?

Please, show how do you generate bytecode, could you decompile it and show the result of decompilation?
Please, see my edited answer.
PS: You can debug the code locally.

Comment: `import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
public class JUnitTest {
 String EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING="r3plac3";
 
 @Test
 public void testReplaceString() {
  InputJavaFile sample = new InputJavaFile();
  
  String outputString = sample.replaceString("replace","e","3");
  Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING, outputString);
 }
}` is my code. 
 
 `obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("testReplaceString").getAnnotation(org.junit.Test.class)`  returns null as well.

Comment: if there is no annotation on method, looks like you generate wrong bytecode  and your class URL contains a tes class without annotations.

Answer (score 0):

This might be class loader related issue, try to create `URLClassLoader` by using constructor and pass class loader of other test class (or just junit class) as is parent class loader, to ensure that JUnit classes are always loaded by the same class loader. And double check that this is right annotation, with right package.

```
public URLClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent)
```

so

```
new URLClassLoader(urlOfToClass, SomeTestOrJUnitClass.class.getClassLoader())
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader(java.net.URL[],%20java.lang.ClassLoader)

Comment: Hi @GotoFinal, Thanks for your response!                         
`System.out.println("Get declared 
    methods==>"+obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("testReplaceString")); System.out.println("Get annotation==>" 
  +obj.getClass().getAnnotation(org.junit.Test.class));`                                       returns `Get declared methods==>public void JUnitTest.testReplaceString() Get annotation==>null`.                                                                                              Not sure why the annotation is lost during dynamic creation. How can the annotation be retained?

Comment: Also `classUrl = 
 Paths.get("/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.class").getParent().toFile().toURI().toURL();
classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { classUrl 
      },obj.getClass().getClassLoader());
System.out.println("classLoader==>"+classLoader);
Class<?> junitcoreClass = Class.forName("org.junit.runner.JUnitCore", 
                   true, classLoader);  
Object junitCore = junitcoreClass.newInstance();`                                           returns          `Exception occured==>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`  . How can this be resolved?

Comment: Don't add junit classes to that class loader... only add proper parent class loader

Comment: Further more issues . The code `File fileForClass = new File(    org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
  System.out.println("classUrl==>" + fileForClass);
  classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { 
                fileForClass.toURI().toURL() });Class<?> junitcoreClass = Class.forName("org.junit.runner.JUnitCore", true, classLoader);JUnitCore junitCore = (JUnitCore) junitcoreClass.newInstance();` returns `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore cannot be cast to org.junit.runner.JUnitCore\n`

Comment: whereas `Class<?> junitcoreClass = Class.forName("org.junit.runner.JUnitCore", true, obj.getClass().getClassLoader());
  JUnitCore junitCore = (JUnitCore) junitcoreClass.newInstance();` returns `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`